# Legend in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, legend

I can´t figure it out how to fit a legend with a graph in Markdown R.

My result looks like this.

[image]

```
plot_druhych_davek = ockovani %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=datum,y=druhych_davek, color = kraj_nazev))+  #+ scale_y_log10() 
  geom_line(alpha = 0.8)+
  labs(title =  str_wrap( sprintf("Průběh druhých dávek očkování od:  %s  DO:  %s", OD, DO),40) ,
       x = "Datum",
       y = "Počet dávek",
       color = "kraj_nazev")+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  theme(axis.title = element_text()) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  


plot(plot_druhych_davek)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I dont have enough Rep to put this as a comment but you might be interested in

```
ggplot(xyz) + scale_color_xxx(guide = guide_legend(keywidth = xxx, keyhight = xxx))
```

this line of code lets you customize your legend quite granularily, however for me always involves a lot of trial and error. There are much more arguments than the ones I used within `guide_legend()`. Good luck!

Comment: Whether things fit or not greatly depend on the size of the graphics device and the fonts you are using, apart from how/where you arrange your legend. When you render graphs in Rmd, you can play with parameters like `fig.width`, `fig.height` and `out.width` to adjust scaling. See also https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html